# Start Android Emulator and perform UI script

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

This is my first question in this amazing service.

So this is what i want to do:
I want to start Android Emulator, perform few actions with UI (fill login/password form and click Login button) and then leave it running.

I wrote some automatic tests with Robotium framework before and know how to make a TEST that running an asserting something. The problem is that test will terminate soon or later. But i need to log in through UI and leave emulator running like some kind of homemade system service.

What would you suggest to solve this problem?

Thanks.